# Can't remove border-bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to custom style the [React mui tabs](https://v3.material-ui.com/demos/tabs/#tabs) in order to accomplish something like this:

[image]

I have tried to set the box-shadow to the selected tab and remove the border-bottom. Setting box-shadow worked, but removing border-bottom didn't. This is the styles object:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper
  },
  selected: {
    boxShadow: theme.shadows[1]
  },
  tab: {
    border: "none"
  }
});
```

And this is how my tab looks like:

```
   <Tab
     label="Item One"
     classes={{ selected: classes.selected, root: classes.tab }}
   />
```

You can see the whole example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-h2jsh).

How am I suppose to remove that border on selected tab? 
On expecting the element in the console I can't even see where the border is coming from.

Comment: I'm getting numerous errors on the page you linked (Firefox 70, Windows 10).

Comment: There is a span after the buttons with background color. It's not a border. It is inside a div with the classes - "MuiTabs-scroller MuiTabs-fixed"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've just found `indicatorColor` Props

```
<Tabs indicatorColor={""} value={value} onChange={this.handleChange}> </Tabs>
```

Ref: https://material-ui.com/api/tabs/

Comment: Does not work for ts. accepts only "primary" | "secondary"

Comment: @softmarshmallow you can add this ts expect error

`
//@ts-expect-error
indicatorColor={''}
`

Comment: To keep typescript happy, you can also use undefined instead of empty string:

<Tabs indicatorColor={undefined} value={value} onChange={this.handleChange}> </Tabs>

Answer (score 1):

You can simply set the element that is being used for that to `display: none;`:

```
<style>
  .MuiTabs-indicator {
    display: none;
  }
</style>
```